# How to reference TinyMCE body in my script

Tags: javascript, tinymce, wp-editor

I want to add some custom behaviour to my TinyMCE body, but I can't reference it in my script.

This is how I load my scripts inside my WordPress plugin:

```
$this->loader->add_filter( 'mce_external_plugins', $plugin_admin, 'tome_editor_tinymce' );

function tome_editor_tinymce( $plugin_array ) {
    $plugin_array['myplugin'] = plugins_url( '/js/tome-editor.js',__FILE__ );

    return $plugin_array;
}
```

And this is how I try to reference TinyMCE body in my `tome-editor.js`:

```
$('#tinymce').css('...');
```

But, jQuery says that `$('#tinymce').length` is **0**

What am I doing wrong?